# Emulator error that shows unexpected token and no stack

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, reactjs, native

[[image: 1]]

I am getting the error in emulator when i run my project by cloning from github. its shows like unexpected token and no stack..

Comment: You need to provide more data on what you are trying to run. How.. etc !  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is it a coincidence that your first question is related to `emulator error` and your name is `emulator error` 

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is, what you are asking about and how you tried to solve it yourself

Comment: I need to get login page in android emulator, where the code is from github link.. i just clone the code from github and typed following commands..

Comment: step1 root file

Comment: step 2: yarn install step 3: then i go to the root file android/app step 4: then i typed key store value step :5 then i compile react-native run android in command prompt

Comment: after compilation its shows like build successful but in emulator unexpected token and no stack error .

Comment: could you please guide !!! and tell me the solution to fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same error!

I search a lot but did not find any satisficed answer At last I delated **yarn.Lock**
and then restart the  project.

It work for me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHh8R.png)

I think the answer I too late. But it will help some other